# How did the Alien know that Ripley was going to blow the Nostromo?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

How could the Alien know that Ellen Ripley is going to blow up the Nostromo?

He deliberately hid himself in the emergency ship in order to survive the explosion.

Did he follow her? Is he super intelligent and knew how human spaceships operate?
Why didn’t he kill her after she sent off the emergency ship?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't the alien kill Ripley in the shuttle craft?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/why-doesnt-the-alien-kill-ripley-in-the-shuttle-craft)

Comment: No, my question is about how Alien knew that he needs to hide in emergency ship. He could hide anywhere on the ship, but he specially chooses to stay in emergency ship.

Comment: Several of the answers on that question specifically address reasons why the Alien may have moved location, in particular [Christopher's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8447/20774). Anything relevant here would undoubtedly be relevant over there as well, hence no need for a second question.